# How to clean out clogged water supply lines in bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, bathtub

I'm a new homeowner. I have somewhat hard water where I live which causes calcium buildup in my water supply lines. My pipes are also pretty old, and it's likely that the previous owner never addressed the mineral buildup in the water lines. Most of the faucets in the house, however, have good pressure and only minimal amounts of calcium/minerals visible in the water. But the shower/tub faucets in the main bathroom have extremely low water pressure, and the water (the hot water in particular) some out extremely cloudy with calcium or whatever it is.

I've taken things apart as much as possible without ripping out tile and getting to the actual plumbing behind the wall. The valve for the tub/shower doesn't seem to be the issue, and nothing is leaking. I did attempt to clean things out by removing the tub and shower faucets and flushing CLR through them. Nothing so far has worked.

Are there any DIY solutions I can use, or am I at the point of calling the plumber?

Comment: It sounds like your root issue may be the quality of the water coming into your house. I would contact a water quality specialist to diagnose the issue, and then you can evaluate possible solutions.  Perhaps a water treatment system at the entry to your house can solve the problem throughout your system.

Comment: Agree with @Armand that a water softener/treatment system is a good long-term solution to prevent the problem returning. However, work will need to be done to remove the scale in the first place. I'll be interested in seeing what the recommendations are. I edited the title to specify "supply", since usually when one thinks of clearing bathroom plumbing, it's on the waste side.

Comment: It has been recommended to me that people should drain some water(a gallon) out of their hot water tank about once a month.  Google found a site that said drain two gallons from tank and add 2 gallons of vinegar.  Open hot water taps still you smell it and then leave closed over night.  In the morning or six hours, open taps till the smell is gone.

Comment: What type of supply pipes do you have? Galvanized pipes with high mineral content water are known to build up on the inside and limit the flow.

Comment: Thanks @Armand and FreeMan, I will definitely be tackling the overall water quality issue soon.

Comment: @crip659 I actually just flushed my entire hot water heater recently. Either way, that's not going to really solve this specific case since it's the tub/shower lines that are having the extreme problem. Plus there's not really a "smell" going on, it's almost definitely clogged pipes due to hard water mineral buildup.

Comment: @EdBeal Those particular pipes are copper.

Comment: Ok I have not observed copper having a buildup but the valves prior to the fixture I have but it sounded like you cleaned them. And the other lines don’t have this issue, can you trace this line back to a common point that branches and the other branch is ok? If the lines are truly plugged it’s time to learn how to replace with copper or plastic it’s a good diy skill to have.

Comment: @EdBeal Those lines also supply water to the sink in that same bathroom. The cold water line also supplies to the toilet. The shower/tub is the last thing on that branch though. Neither of those are experiencing this issue. So is there no practical way to clean out the lines short of replacing them?

Comment: I was looking for a way to cut the problem down to a logical half split , the feeling I get from you is hostile, I will quit trying. Call a plumber as that is your best chance from what i see.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm confused. I'm just trying to find out if I have any options before I go the route of replacing plumbing? I appreciate your knowledge and advice, I just wanted to make sure what all my options are. I apologize if I came across as hostile, I was just trying to be direct in answering your question.